# Is it possible to undefine a variable in ColdFusion?

Tags: syntax, coldfusion

Is it possible to undefine a variable in ColdFusion?

For example, something like this:

```
<cfset myVar = "lsajflksd" />
<cfoutput>
  <p>myVar is Defined? #IsDefined("myVar")#</p> <!--- Prints YES --->
</cfoutput>
<cfset Undefine(myVar) /> <!--- Doesn't exist... --->
<cfoutput>
  <p>myVar is Defined? #IsDefined("myVar")#</p> <!--- I want it to print NO --->
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
<cfset StructDelete(Variables, "myVar") />
```

`Variables` is the default scope for most variables in most contexts.

Comment: Note that this is a recent feature. Older versions of CF can't do this.

Comment: Sorry. All I know is Adobe CF 8.01.

Answer (score 4):

In modern versions, you can also use the struct.delete() member function.

```
myVar = "lsajflksd";

variables.delete('myVar');
```

https://docs.lucee.org/reference/objects/struct/delete.html

Comment: The newer syntax is more elegant than what was available back in '09 :-)

Answer (score 3):

FYI...

```
<cffunction name="voidFunc" returntype="void">
</cffunction>

<cfset myVar = voidFunc()>
<cfoutput>#IsDefined("myVar")#</cfoutput>    <!--- will show NO --->
```

I found out from this blog entry: [cfinvoke destroys returnVariable for methods that return void](http://www.ghidinelli.com/2009/01/27/cfinvoke-destroys-returnvariable-for-methods-that-return-void)

Comment: Be advised [CF2018 introduced null support](https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2018/07/null-support-in-coldfusion-2018/), and when enabled, the method does NOT "undefine" the variable. The value will be null, but both StructKeyExists/IsDefined will return `true`.